# Assigning same memory to class member variables using unions

Tags: c++, vector, simd, vectorization, altivec

I am trying to vectorize existing Vector class

```
class Vector
{
 public:
   float X,Y,Z;
};
```

Trying to vectorize the class members without affecting other classes accessing the these member variable

```
class Vector
{
 public:
   union{
      float X,Y,Z;
      vector float vec4;
   };
};
```

But there is a compiler error as no memeber name X,Y,Z found. Is there a alternative way to get the variable?

For reference, the `vector float` type comes from the [IBM™ Cell Broadband Engine™ 
Software Development Kit V3.0 for Multicore Acceleration](http://moss.csc.ncsu.edu/~mueller/cluster/ps3/SDK3.0/docs/accessibility/sdkpt/cbet_2cplus_vecttyp.html).

Comment: This line looks pretty wrong: `vector float vec4;`.

Comment: http://moss.csc.ncsu.edu/~mueller/cluster/ps3/SDK3.0/docs/accessibility/sdkpt/cbet_2cplus_vecttyp.html

Comment: Ah, I see. Sorry for that. But maybe you should've mentioned that. :)

Comment: Declaring three floats in one declarator doesn't magically make them one "entity". It's just a shorthand. You'll have to wrap them in some struct.

Answer (score 0):

```
struct VectorData {
  float X, Y, Z;
};

union VectorUnion {
  VectorData VecData;
  vector float vec4;
};


class Vector {
public:
  Vector() : X(u.VecData.X), Y(u.VecData.Y), Z(u.VecData.Z) {}
  float & X;
  float & Y;
  float & Z;
private:
  VectorUnion u;
};
```

This is the closest I believe you can get with standard C++ - This makes Vector larger, and requires you to implement the assignment operator yourself.

Comment: I think it was MSVC that lifted an anonymous union's members into the parent scope as an extension?

Comment: @Erik: `vector float vec4;' wont really compile!

Comment: @Als: See Rinesh's comment - he's using some SIMD extension which defines a.o the type `vector float`

Comment: Isnt there a way to access the variables X,Y,Z as before and having vec4 to point to the same location.

Comment: @Rinesh: Not in standard c++ - MSVC supports "unnamed union" though.

Comment: @Erik: Just saw that!! thats a evil extension!

Comment: @Erik: with what you have `&(u.X) == &(u.Y) == &(u.Z)`. you need another struct level in there.

Comment: @Mat: ahh yes - sorry, I blame lack of coffee.

Comment: @Rinesh: Updated answer - this approach'll let you keep external use of Vector unmodified, but it comes with a cost.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do that in standard C++ using union. You may only read what you have previously written. So writing `X`, `Y`, `Z` and then reading `vec4` yields undefined behavior.

I would suggest to create a member function `vector float toVector() const` that will create the vector when needed. Or you may consider defining a member `operator vector float() const`.

Comment: Yes it's UB, but it's near-universally supported safely and the UB often ignored... and that by people who usually (and quite rightly) avoid UB like the plague. Make of that what you will.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do quite exactly what you want (using the syntax from your code).

One example correct way to do it:

```
union{
    float coords[4];
    vector float vec4;
};
```

And then you can pick off element by element.

Alternatively:

```
union{
    struct {
        float X, Y, Z;
    } v;
    vector float vec4;
};
```

But then you access values via `.v.X`

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Point
{
public:
    Point() { X = 0.0f; Y = 0.0f; Z = 0.0f; };
    ~Point() {};

    union
    {
        struct{
            float X; float Y; float Z;
        };
        float index[3];
    };

    float operator[](int it)
    {
        return index[it];
    };
};

void main()
{
    Point p;

    p.X = 1.0f;
    p.Y = 2.0f;
    p.Z = 3.0f;

    cout << p[0] << " " << p[1] << " " << p[2] << endl;

    p.index[0] = 4.0f;
    p.index[1] = 5.0f;
    p.index[2] = 6.0f;

    cout << p[0] << " " << p[1] << " " << p[2] << endl;

    cin.get();
}
```